# Does additivity of $ f_1(x)g_1(y) + f_2(x)g_2(y)$ tells us something about $f_1, f_2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2$ be non-constant continuous real functions, such that
$
f_1(x)g_1(y) + f_2(x)g_2(y)
$
is additive in $x,y$, that is, there exist functions $f,g$ such that
$$
f_1(x)g_1(y) + f_2(x)g_2(y) = f(x) + g(y), \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

What does it imply for $f_1, \dots, g_2$? Is it true that $f_1(x) = af_2(x)+b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?

What about the case when we have $n$ pairs of functions, i.e. when $
f_1(x)g_1(y) + \dots + f_n(x)g_n(y)
$ is additive?

Comment: If all the functions are smooth, you can differentiate the equality and so you can get $f_{1}'(x)g_{1}(y)+f_{2}'(x)g_{2}(y)=f'(x)$ and $f_{1}(x)g_{1}'(y)+f_{2}(x)g_{2}'(y)=g'(y)$. But I don't know how to do next, sorry.

Comment: maybe we can differentiate again, we can get $f_{1}'(x)g_{1}'(y)+f_{2}'(x)g_{2}'(y)=0$, that is to say vector$(f_{1}'(x),f_{2}'(x))$ is perpendicular to $(g_{1}'(y),g_{2}'(y))$

Comment: or say $\frac{f_{1}'(x)}{f_{2}'(x)}=-\frac{g_{2}'(y)}{g_{1}'(y)}=constant\ independent\ of\ x\ and\ y$

Comment: then we have $f_{1}'(x)=constant\ f_{2}'(x)$ and $g_{2}'(x)=-constant\ g_{1}'(x)$

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how I got the idea of $f_1(x) = af_2(x) + b$. But we can not assume differentiability and I don't know how to generalize this for $n$ variables.

Comment: so we have $f_{1}(x)=constant\ f_{2}(x)+Constant$ for $g_{1},g_{2}$, similarly.

Comment: Yes,@AlbertParadek, my idea is not suitable for your question.

Comment: The following answer is beautiful, I learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
f_1(x)g_1(y) + f_2(x)g_2(y) = f(x) + g(y), \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Put $y=0$. We have
$$
f_1(x)g_1(0) + f_2(x)g_2(0) = f(x) + g(0), \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Hence
$$
f_1(x)(g_1(y)- g_1(0))+ f_2(x)(g_2(y)-g_2(0)) = g(y)-g(0), \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Suppose that $g_1(y_0) \ne g_1(0)$ (such $y_0$ exists because $g_1$ is not constant) and put $y=y_0$. We have
$$ c_1 f_1(x) + c_2f_2(x) = c_3 $$
where $c_1 \ne 0$ as you wanted.

We also get that $$ d_1 g_1(x) + d_2g_2(x) = d_3, \quad d_1 \ne 0$$ by similar argument.

If the number of pairs $n > 2$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i f_i(x) = C$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i g_i(x) = D$.